# Is there a word that encompasses both "compensation" and "reimbursement"?

Tags: terminology, refund, compensation, reimbursement

Here on [wordreference.com](https://forum.wordreference.com/threads/reimbursement-vs-compensation.2856710/post-14437686)  I was reading that:

> - Reimbursement is specifically giving back the same amount of money they paid.
> - Compensation is wider - it means giving them something, usually money, and usually not the exact thing they most want.

Even though they're not exactly the same, is there another financial term/category that would encompass both concepts?

Comment: What's the context? _Inflow_ is one word that comes to mind but it depends on the context you're going to use it in.

Comment: This is probably better suited for https://ell.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Well I previously posted in ell and then be forwarded to pfm for the same kind of topic.

Comment: As you've already said, the concept *compensation* is broader.  Since it encompasses and includes *reimbursement*, *compensation* is a valid answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The term *payment* would encompass both reimbursement and compensation.